# I'm looking for capture card software that works on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, video

I have a (very) old Capture Card in my machine, and I decided to try windows 7. The problem is, the software that comes with the card doesn't work on windows 7 (not did it work on vista).

I tryed to install the card in the media center, but after a lot of tinkering all I get is VERY delayed video with no audio, that stops after about a minute complaining about Low Bit Rate.

The card still works in windows xp on the same machine.

So how can I fix this, or what software can I get that will work on windows 7 and display video and audio from the card?

Comment: Which "capture card" do you have?

Comment: Device Manager Reports FlyTV P30+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with [DScaler](http://www.dscaler.org/dscaler4.htm), took some time to tweek it and all, but after that, it works even better than the native application that came with the card back in XP.

Answer (score 0):

The driver model has changed from XP to Vista/Win7. This means that you can't install the XP driver on Win7.
The only advice I have is to try and find a Win7 driver, maybe from the manufacturer.
Please note that a Vista driver has excellent chances of working in Win7.

Comment: I got a driver from windows update. And it seems to work as I can actualy see video in the media center. So I need some software that works good just for viewing.